# Duplicate "iCloud Drive (Archive)" folders

Tags: macos, icloud, folders, mojave

I have two **iCloud Drive** folders.

Is this normal behaviour?
Can I *delete* one (how about both)?

[image: Finder]
[image]

Running macOS Mojave 10.14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When turning iCloud Drive off, files that were contained in iCloud Drive are saved to a newly created folder called "iCloud Drive (Archive)" (if the option to save files is selected when turning iCloud Drive off).

Turning iCloud Drive on and off again will create additional folders, such as "iCloud Drive (Archive) - 1", and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Neither of these are your actual iCloud Drive folders where your iCloud Drive data is stored.
If you don't need their contents, you can delete both of them.

iCloud Drive data is stored in `~/Library/Mobile Documents`

If you don’t have that folder, then it means your machine isn’t hosting a cached copy of iCloud data locally.

Comment: You can't because `Library` is an hidden folder. You can view hidden folders by pressing SHIFT + CMD + . in the Finder App.